# Undefined property for public var in Model class?

Tags: atk4

I'm somewhat confused about the following snipped of code which simply checks if a column exists in the table before adding it to the Model with addField().

strangely however, PHP error_log warns me that the public variable is not properly defined the first time I use it:

```
/var/www/ocmal_db_svn/lib/Model/Conflicto.php:[Notice] Undefined property: Model_Conflicto::$entity_code,
```

which is why the SQL query throws an error because 'SHOW columns FROM ' is incomplete without the table name...

defining a public variable within the class should initialize it, no?
or is something else going wrong?  can anyone see an error here? 
what am I overlooking? (this is PHP 5.3 BTW)

```
class Model_Conflicto extends Model_Table {

      public $entity_code='conflicto';

        function init(){
             parent::init();

               if ($this->api->db->dsql()->expr("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `". $this->entity_code. "` LIKE 'lock_id'")->getOne()==null)
          error_log('OCMAL_DB: WARNING: table '.$this->entity_code.' does not have lock_id, which is kinda BAD !!!');
        else $this->addField('lock_id');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not a full answer to your question, because I don't really get the point of this, but:

1) You should use public $table='conflicto' and not $entity_code because $entity_code is obsolete (but still usable for compatibility reasons)

2) I don't see any reason why you need to check if field exists in table before adding it to model. Is it possible that somebody simply delete field from database without notice and don't remove it from Model? If that's the case, then you need to change something in your project management and not create messy and veeeeeery slow code :)
Do you imagine how big stress that will generate to your database if for every initialization of this Model you'll query SHOW columns FROM table?!

Comment: thanks for your comments. obviously this isn't production yet, and the error_log is there for testing & compatibility reasons. I'll replace entity_code with table as you suggest and see what that does.

Comment: ah yes: I see now, in Model_Table:   `function __construct(){
        if($this->entity_code){
            $this->table=$this->entity_code;
            unset($this->entity_code);
        }
    }`